# xslt copy deepest node to file

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
    <CUSTOMER>
        <phonenumber>+0002443333</phonenumber>
        <email>blabla@blabla.com</email>
        <category>36465194</category>
        <segment>SB</segment>
    </CUSTOMER>
</DATA>
```

My need is to select deepest element + it's parent and create new file name from it and copy the data of this deepest element + surrounding xml structure.

so for example there will be file `CUSTOMER_phonenumber.xml` and it will contain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
    <CUSTOMER>
        <phonenumber>+0002443333</phonenumber>
    </CUSTOMER>
</DATA>
```

Currently I have following xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="DATA/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[not(*)]">
            <xsl:variable name="parentTag">
                <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="currentTag">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$parentTag}_{$currentTag}.xml" indent="yes">
                <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::*[@currentTag]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Where I can successfully create output files and put there the deepest element, but I don't know how to copy the structure.

So how can I copy only one element with it's structure?

Thanks

Comment: Which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use exactly? If it is a version of Saxon 9 that also supports XSLT 3.0 then you could simply use the `snapshot` function on your leaf elements.

Comment: Unfortunately only xslt 2.0

Comment: You could use the XSLT implementation of the snapshot() function found at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the ancestors and process them, in a single mode stylesheet the following does that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[not(*)]">
            <xsl:result-document href="test2016071403Result{position()}.xml">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::*[last()]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="tree" select="ancestor-or-self::*"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="tree"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($tree[2])">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$tree[2]">
                        <xsl:with-param name="tree" select="$tree[position() gt 1]"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

if you also want to use the default mode for other processing/output, then use a different mode e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[not(*)]">
            <xsl:result-document href="test2016071403Result{position()}.xml">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::*[last()]" mode="tree">
                    <xsl:with-param name="tree" select="ancestor-or-self::*"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="tree">
        <xsl:param name="tree"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($tree[2])">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$tree[2]" mode="tree">
                        <xsl:with-param name="tree" select="$tree[position() gt 1]"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As your naming scheme `href="{$parentTag}_{$currentTag}.xml"` would result in problems if there are two elements of the same name I have not used that but of course the above does allow you to use your naming scheme if you are sure there can be no elements of the same name.

Comment: I'm using this function for testing so your first example helped me a lot. Thanks.